# Is there a limit to the number of cyclones that can be spawned from Sweeping Wind?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I like the [Cyclone rune](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/sweeping-wind/c) for [Sweeping Wind](http://d3db.com/skill/i/sweeping-wind), and it seems to be pretty powerful, but I was wondering about how much value I should place on `+crit chance` gear. Is there a limit on how many Cyclones can be spawned at once? I'm sure that I've seen multiple spawn at once from a Fists of Thunder, so I don't think there is an internal cooldown and I've also seen 5-6 spawned at once. But that still doesn't prove anything, so my question: Does anyone know if there is a limit (hard, or soft like an internal CD) on how many cyclones can be spawned at the same time?

Comment: I feel as if there is something limiting it: I just had 5 cyclones up on a single-target pull at ~17% crit chance, but many AoE groups I don't get many more. It would be nice to know one way or the other though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a limit. If there is one, it's quite likely to be unreachable.

Here is a screenshot of 5 simultaneous cyclones made using a 21% crit chance and several crits per second.

[screenshot http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/558692204679386275/A0715CB169CE0AA81FAA7A28F431A6600DB23151/](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/558692204679386275/A0715CB169CE0AA81FAA7A28F431A6600DB23151/)

You have to remember that not only do they only spawn when you crit, but it's also a *chance* to spawn. Getting many more than 5 is very unlikely, they despawn very quickly.

Comment: When I have more than a couple enemies around, I can hit a few with Fists of Thunder and generate more than 5 at the same time occasionally, which is why I was curious. It seems like stacking crit chance and ignoring crit damage could cause an aweful lot of damage as each crit has a (good) chance to proc an extra 20% of your damage for 3 seconds. If you could keep up 4-5 you would be effectively doubling your single target dps,

Comment: Yes, and if there is a limit, it may be something like 256 or 64 or something else arbitrary to stop the engine from creating too many due to an unknown bug and crashing the game. It's not likely that there is a limit on how many you can spawn, you just need to be fast enough and crit often enough.